Providing object(polygon) into trim functon in autocad using pyautocad
How to pass an object in code instead of choosing it manually in drawing? My object is saved to variable "new_obj" and I want to pass it as a cutting edge.
Code is something like this:
command = f"._trim {new_obj}"

doc.SendCommand(command)

But Autocad do not take "new_obj" as an object. It takes it as a string.
Is there an option to pass an object instead of select it manually in AutoCAD window?
